# Probability change with number of trials

Tags: probability

My question is the following:
Suppose I have collected data about some process with two possibilities (0 or 1). There was 5 events in which all of them came out as 0. So, I could say that the probability of the next event being 0 is 1 (100%) and being 1 is 0(0%). 
But this is not true. The probability could be 50/50% and the events come out all 0's. 
That being the case, how can I find the probability corrected for the number of events that I encounter in the data? (Like, 100 events being all 0's gives much more confidence that the probability of the process is 100/0% than just 5 events).

Thank You,
João

Comment: There's very little you can say without more information, and $5$ is a very small sample.  If you know more about the situation you can try to design a mathematical model for it.  If you have some a priori belief or knowledge concerning the distribution, you can use the new information to calibrate and refrain that understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lulu has already stated in a comment, you need to specify your prior beliefs about the distribution of the outcomes in order to compute the posterior beliefs you should rationally hold after the experiment. For the situation you describe, one possible prior belief is for the probability $p$ of obtaining a result of $1$ to be uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. This leads to the [rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession), which states that after seeing $s$ $1$s in $n$ experiments, the expected value of $p$ is $\frac{s+1}{n+2}$. In your case, this would yield an expected value of $\frac{0+1}{5+2}=\frac17$ for $p$, so you'd expect the next event to yield a $1$ with probability $\frac17$. But again, this is just one possible answer, and only you can decide, ideally based on a model of the process, what your prior beliefs about $p$ are; probability theory can only tell you how to update them to your posterior beliefs, based on the data from the experiment.

Comment: Alright. I'm getting somewhere. There is no prior knowledge about the distribution. The process is unknown. But the question can be put in a different way.
Knowing that I took 4 0's and 1 1's, what is the probability that the coin follows a probability of 1/2 (balanced)? Or 1/4-3/4? 

Thanks again..

Comment: @Rodolfo: I'm afraid we're not getting through to you :-). The answer is precisely the same as for the original question: There's not enough information to answer that. You'd need to specify your prior beliefs in order for there to be a well-defined answer to that question. However, you might want to look into [hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).

Comment: @Rodolfo: While this doesn't allow you to deduce the probability you ask about (only a [Bayesian approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability), which requires a prior, does that), it does give you a systematic way to decide whether to reject a certain hypothesis or not, e.g. the hypothesis that the coin is fair ($p=\frac12$). It does so with a certain level of significance, which you can specify and which can be interpreted as the probability of falsely rejecting the hypothesis under the condition that it's true (which is quite distinct from the probability that you ask about).

Comment: Rule of Succession seems fine :) Thank you